# Ball-Box Collision Detection

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, game-development

```js
var canvas,cxt,h,w,mousePos;
var player= {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    color: 'black'
};

function init(){
    canvas= document.querySelector('#style');
    cxt= canvas.getContext('2d');
    h= canvas.height;
    w= canvas.width;
    createBalls(10);
    main();
}

function createBalls(c){
    ball= [];
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        var k= {
            x: h/2,
            y: w/2,
            color: colorGenerate(),
            radius: 5+Math.round(30*Math.random()), 
            a: -5+Math.round(10*Math.random()),
            b: -5+Math.round(10*Math.random())
        }
        ball.push(k);
    }
}

function main(){
    cxt.clearRect(0,0,h,w);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
        mousePos= getMousePos(canvas,evt);
    });
    createPlayer();
    draw(ball.length);
    ballAlive();
    move(ball.length);
    movePlayer();
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

function ballAlive(){
    cxt.save();
    cxt.font="30px Arial";
    if(ball.length==0) cxt.fillText("You Win",20,20);
    else cxt.fillText(ball.length,20,40);
    cxt.restore();
}

function getMousePos(canvas,evt){
    var rect= canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return{
        x: evt.clientX-rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY-rect.top
    }
}

function createPlayer(){
    cxt.save();
    cxt.translate(0,0);
    cxt.fillStyle= player.color;
    cxt.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.height,player.width);
    cxt.restore();
}

function movePlayer(){
    if(mousePos !== undefined){
        player.x= mousePos.x;
        player.y= mousePos.y;
    }
}

function draw(d){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<d;i++){
        cxt.save();
        cxt.translate(0,0);
        cxt.beginPath();
        cxt.fillStyle= ball[i].color;
        cxt.arc(ball[i].x,ball[i].y,ball[i].radius,0,2*Math.PI)
        cxt.fill();
        cxt.restore();
    }
}

function move(m){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        ball[i].x+= ball[i].a;
        ball[i].y+= ball[i].b;
        checkCollision(ball[i]);
        checkCollisionPlayer(ball[i],i);
    }
}

function checkCollision(n){
    if(n.x+n.radius>w){
        n.a= -n.a;
        n.x= w-n.radius;
    }
    else if(n.x-n.radius<0){
        n.a= -n.a;
        n.x= n.radius;
    }
    if(n.y+n.radius>h){
        n.b= -n.b;
        n.y= h-n.radius;
    }
    else if(n.y-n.radius<0){
        n.b= -n.b;
        n.y= n.radius;
    }
}

function checkCollisionPlayer(n,j){
    if(overlap(n.x,n.y,n.radius,player.x,player.y,player.height,player.width)){
        ball.splice(j,1);
    }
}

function overlap(cx,cy,r,px,py,ph,pw){
    var testX= cx;
    var testY= cy;
// THESE LINES ARE FOR MOVING THE BALLS TOWARDS THE PLAYER
    if(testX<px) testX=px;
    if(testX>(px+pw)) testX=px+pw;
    if(testY<py) testy=py;
    if(testY>(py+ph)) testY=py+ph;

    //DISTANCE FORMULA FOR CHECKING THE OVERLAPING BETWEEN THE BOX AND CIRCLE
    return((cx-px)*(cx-px)+(cy-py)*(cy-py)<r*r);
}

function colorGenerate(){
    var col= ['green','blue','pink','red','brown','yellow','black','orange','grey','golden'];
    var i= Math.round((col.length-1)*Math.random());  //RETURN VALUES FROM 0 TO 9
    return col[i];
}
```

```css
 #style{
    border: 4px dotted green;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= 'en-us'>
    <head>
        <title>Feed The Monster</title>
 
    </head>
    <body onload= 'init();'>
        <canvas id= 'style' height= '400' width= '400'>
            Your browser does not support canvas...
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting error in my code as soon as the first collision takes place between the player(box) and the balls.
The only part which is giving error is the `splice()` function. If I comment the `splice()` function then code is not showing any error. 
But if I use `splice()` function part in my code then it is showing error in the move function and I don't know why this is happening.
Please help me…

Comment: Please add the error to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas,cxt,h,w,mousePos;
var player= {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    color: 'black'
};

function init(){
    canvas= document.querySelector('#style');
    cxt= canvas.getContext('2d');
    h= canvas.height;
    w= canvas.width;
    createBalls(10);
    main();
}

function createBalls(c){
    ball= [];
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        var k= {
            x: h/2,
            y: w/2,
            color: colorGenerate(),
            radius: 5+Math.round(30*Math.random()), 
            a: -5+Math.round(10*Math.random()),
            b: -5+Math.round(10*Math.random())
        }
        ball.push(k);
    }
}

function main(){
    cxt.clearRect(0,0,h,w);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
        mousePos= getMousePos(canvas,evt);
    });
    createPlayer();
    draw(ball.length);
    ballAlive();
    move(ball);
    movePlayer();
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

function ballAlive(){
    cxt.save();
    cxt.font="30px Arial";
    if(ball.length==0) cxt.fillText("You Win",20,20);
    else cxt.fillText(ball.length,20,40);
    cxt.restore();
}

function getMousePos(canvas,evt){
    var rect= canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return{
        x: evt.clientX-rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY-rect.top
    }
}

function createPlayer(){
    cxt.save();
    cxt.translate(0,0);
    cxt.fillStyle= player.color;
    cxt.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.height,player.width);
    cxt.restore();
}

function movePlayer(){
    if(mousePos !== undefined){
        player.x= mousePos.x;
        player.y= mousePos.y;
    }
}

function draw(d){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<d;i++){
        cxt.save();
        cxt.translate(0,0);
        cxt.beginPath();
        cxt.fillStyle= ball[i].color;
        cxt.arc(ball[i].x,ball[i].y,ball[i].radius,0,2*Math.PI)
        cxt.fill();
        cxt.restore();
    }
}

function move(m){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<m.length;i++){
        ball[i].x+= ball[i].a;
        ball[i].y+= ball[i].b;
        checkCollision(ball[i]);
        checkCollisionPlayer(ball[i],i);
    }
}

function checkCollision(n){
    if(n.x+n.radius>w){
        n.a= -n.a;
        n.x= w-n.radius;
    }
    else if(n.x-n.radius<0){
        n.a= -n.a;
        n.x= n.radius;
    }
    if(n.y+n.radius>h){
        n.b= -n.b;
        n.y= h-n.radius;
    }
    else if(n.y-n.radius<0){
        n.b= -n.b;
        n.y= n.radius;
    }
}

function checkCollisionPlayer(n,j){
    if(overlap(n.x,n.y,n.radius,player.x,player.y,player.height,player.width)){
        ball.splice(j,1);
    }
}

function overlap(cx,cy,r,px,py,ph,pw){
    var testX= cx;
    var testY= cy;
// THESE LINES ARE FOR MOVING THE BALLS TOWARDS THE PLAYER
    if(testX<px) testX=px;
    if(testX>(px+pw)) testX=px+pw;
    if(testY<py) testy=py;
    if(testY>(py+ph)) testY=py+ph;

    //DISTANCE FORMULA FOR CHECKING THE OVERLAPING BETWEEN THE BOX AND CIRCLE
    return((cx-px)*(cx-px)+(cy-py)*(cy-py)<r*r);
}

function colorGenerate(){
    var col= ['green','blue','pink','red','brown','yellow','black','orange','grey','golden'];
    var i= Math.round((col.length-1)*Math.random());  //RETURN VALUES FROM 0 TO 9
    return col[i];
}
```

```css
#style{
        border: 4px dotted green;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= 'en-us'>
    <head>
        <title>Feed The Monster</title>
 
    </head>
    <body onload= 'init();'>
        <canvas id= 'style' height= '400' width= '400'>
            Your browser does not support canvas...
        </canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you pass the array as an argument in the move() function not the length of the array then your code will work perfectly.

Comment: Although it seems to work fine, this solution is not as good as the one I suggested. The issue is that it will not go over every object in the `ball` array. Simplified example: if it has 2 objects in it, and the first one (index `0`) gets deleted - then when the index increases to `1`, that is equal to the the new length of the array, so the loop won't continue and the second object will not get updated. This may not be an issue, since the loop is repeated every frame, but depending on what else is going on it's possible this could cause problems, whose cause could be hard to diagnose later.

Comment: @Robin Sir -  well i don't think the loop will stop as per your example, because if there are 2 objects and index 0 element gets deleted then the second(index 1) element will get shifted to index 0 and the length of the array will become 1 ,  so the loop will continue to execute.

Comment: indeed the second element will get shifted to index 0, and that's the problem - index 0 has already been covered (the object that started there has been deleted), the loop then moves on to index 1, which doesn't exist any more. No error is thrown because `1` fails the `< m.length` check, but the object which was originally at index 1 never gets checked/updated. (Until the next time the loop is ran.) You could fix this by decrementing the loop variable (`i`) whenever an object is deleted - but at this point the code can easily start to get quite messy.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be to do with the loop inside your `move` function. You call it with the parameter `m` representing the lengh of the `ball` array - but the function `checkCollisionPlayer` which is called within that can remove a ball from the array if there is a collision. This means that the array is now shorter, so whenever you try to access a property on `ball[m-1]` later in the loop, as you will, you'll get this error.

I'm sure there are lots of different ways to fix this. The easiest I can think of (which I have successfully used myself in making a browser game) is to, instead of directly deleting the balls from the array upon collision, set a property on them to mark them as "deleted". Then add a "cleanup" function onto the end of the loop to filter the array into only those that are not marked as deleted. This ensures that every object you are looping over actually exists, while still changing the length dynamically to reflect the game state.

Comment: I am passing ball.length(array length) as an argument in the move function so if i use splice(index,1) it will remove the element of the specific index and will also shift the indexes of the other elements at the same time so i don't think error is coming because of this.

Comment: I know you're passing it in, the problem though is that it doesn't change while the function is running, even if the length updates. You loop with `i` going from `0` to `m-1`, but if the array length reduces partway through then `ball[i]` will no longer exist when `i` is `m-1`. And once you've started the loop then you will always have a time when `i` is `m-1` (unless you manually mess with the loop partway through, which I wouldn't recommend). Why don't you try the fix I suggested, which is very simple to implement?